# Linking to the route error in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this route:

```
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::get('/users/create', 'UserController@create');
```

and the controller function is:

```
 public function index()
  {
    $users=User::all();
    return View('users.index',compact('users'));    

 }
```

And i have this code in `index.blade.php` where shows the **error**:

```
<p>{{ link_to_route('users.create', 'Add new user') }}</p>
```

the error message is:

> Route [users.create] not defined. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\larapro\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it like this if you wish the route mentioned in your view to work.

```
Route::get('users/create', ['as' => 'users.create', 'uses' =>'UserController@create']);
```

Although it should be noted that `Route::resource()` gives you the index, create, edit, store, show, update, delete routes. So you are writing redundant code declaring the route a second time.

It is effectively replacing the route you have previously created using `Route::resource`

See Laravel documentation on this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

if you run `php artisan route:list` inside your project folder you should see a list of routes created for the resource 'users' which you have declared above.

Alternatively, remove the second route you declared as the Route::resource should take care of it all.

Comment: ok. it worked. but why should i not require that for this `{{ link_to_route('users.edit', 'Edit', array($user->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}`

Answer (score 1):

This line is redundant and should be removed:

```
Route::get('/users/create', 'UserController@create');
```

It causes the problem you describe because...

1. `Route::resource()` already registers a route just like this one, and automatically names it `users.create`.
2. When you register your route for `/users/create`, it **replaces the existing route** for that URL with the new route.
3. Your new route hasn't been given a name.
4. Since the new route replaces the existing route (which was named `users.create`), there's now no route with that name.

So when you try to generate a link there, you'll get the `Route [users.create] not defined` exception.